# Scaling image using Bitmaptransform gives blured images in win2d

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

This is what I have tried:

```
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
BitmapTransform bitmapTransform = new BitmapTransform();
bitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 300;
bitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 800;

var pixelProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                    BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                    BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                    bitmapTransform,
                    ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
                    ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

byte[] by = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();
CanvasBitmap cb = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(sender,by,800,300,Windows.Graphics.DirectX.DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8X8UIntNormalized);
```

What I have done in the Draw event of CanvasControl:

```
private  void Canvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(cb);
}
```

Due to scaling, the image gets blurred. How can I solve this issue? I need to change the width and height of image dynamically at run time, how can I do that?
My Original Image:
[image: n]

After Draw (Blured Image):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens, it means that your picture resolution exceeds the control size you have given. And the pixel aliasing is caused by the interpolation algorithm.

By default, the interpolation algorithm used when the image is zoomed is `Linear`, if you want to render a larger resolution image on a smaller control, you can use the `Fant` algorithm.

```cs
bitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 300;
bitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 800;
bitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;
```

If you plan to dynamically change the width and height of the picture, it is recommended to use `ViewBox` as the `CanvasControl` container.

```xml
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" x:Name="MyViewbox">
    <xaml:CanvasControl />
</Viewbox>
```

Then you can change the size of the Viewbox at runtime.

```cs
MyViewbox.Width = 400;
MyViewbox.Height = 150;
```

Thanks.

Comment: @ Richard Zhang -MSFT , Viewbox Won't work for my case,because I need to draw mutiple images in one canvasControl at different Location.But InterpolationMode.Fant helped me.Now the Image drawed looks better than before.But still there is some little blur .Is there any other Accurate way??

Comment: The other simple way is to use Image control with **BitmapImage**, for example: `MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage (new Uri ("image_url")) {DecodePixelWidth = 800}` But the scaling of the picture is the process of rearranging the pixels. You can imagine put 1000x1000 small balls of different colors in a 100x100 box, and in the end will lose a lot of information. Different algorithms will rearrange pixels in different ways. At present, four algorithms are available in `InterpolationMode`, but no matter which one, there will be trade-offs for pixels, and the final effect will always have flaws.

Comment: Whether it is `CanvasControl` or Image, the principle of scaling and re-arranging according to the size of the control is consistent, you can try other `BitmapInterpolationMode` to see which one suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Win2d effects to quickly get the job done.

```
 var ScaledImage = new Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects.ScaleEffect(
Source = source, new Vector2(2f, 2f);)
```

The function above produces a `ScaleEffect`, which implements `ICanvasBitmap` so you can can directly render it with  `DrawingSession.DrawImage`